# Artifactory OSS edition has no maintenance operations

Tags: artifactory

I'd like to run Garbage Collection as the [document](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF5X/Regular+Maintenance+Operations#RegularMaintenanceOperations-GarbageCollection), But could not find Advanced in Admin module. Although [Artifactory Comparison Matrix](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Comparison+Matrix) said that OSS edition still support Maintenance.
Is there something I could do to enable this function?
I'm using Artifactory version 6.20
Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Artifactory are you using? the linked documentation is relevant for version 5.x while the latest is 7.x and many things have changes in the UI

Comment: I'm using version 6.20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Maintenance option does exist in the Artifactory 6.x admin UI

[image]

The only option I can think of is that you are not logged in as an admin user

Answer (score 1):

That's interested, the Advanced option just show up when I using a high resolution screen.
The capture below is Admin UI in laptop screen.
[image]

Comment: I had the same problem. On my laptop screen, the "Advanced" section was missing entirely, but was contained in the HTML. I was inspecting other HTML elements under "Import & Export", scrolling down the list to find the hidden menu items I needed, and pasting those URLs into the URL/search bar at the top of my browser. It worked, but was a huge pain.

Your comment helped me. When I just move the browser window from my laptop monitor to my external second monitor, all the menu items show up. Annoying bug, but this workaround is much easier than mine was. Thank you!